# Naming convention in sharepoint, file with comma in name is giving error

Tags: metadata

I am facing issue with file name in document library which contain "," comma in its naming convention like abc,xyz.doc

Error comes while opening or exporting file.
I saw that comma is not recommended by microsoft but we have 80% file with comma naming convention. Is their any workaround for this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There are certain characters that you cannot use in files in SharePoint. You will have to adhere to these instructions otherwise you will not be allowed to upload files with such names to SharePoint.

If you want to upload such files then either you will have to write a utility which removes special characters from file name.

below is the link with some more details:
[Click here]http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905231

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint will not allow you to upload files with commas, my suggestion would be to rename files, a few ways to do this, either use Windows explorer, power shell, command prompt (ren)

http://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/

Third Part tools: http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php

Or using powershell: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/11/22/use-powershell-to-rename-files-in-bulk.aspx

Comment: I am able to upload filename with comma like abc,xyz.pdf but after uploading it show error while we open and load.Does we have to rename file without comma only?

Comment: Yes that is correct, you will have to get rid of any special characters from the file name before uploading the file. View this article from Microsoft about special characters (Information about the characters that you cannot use in site names, folder names, and file names in SharePoint) : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905231

Comment: The above site does not include comma as special character which hsould not be used

Answer (score 0):

I was able to import the folders we had with Commas in them using "" around the network path values and destination folder values (Example -- "\\SERVER\SHARE\SMITH, JOHN" and for destination folder - "SMITH, JOHN").  I don't believe a comma is one of the "not allowed" characters in Sharepoint, but it does present problems using the SPMT tool and doing the bulk migration with a CSV file (commas are the separators in CSV files, and this can't be changed to another separator in SPMT).  I had to mess with those values in Excel to insert all the quotes in the proper fields around the network path and folder destination fields, but once done, the SPMT migration ran fine.

I know this is an old thread, but I needed to do this today and couldn't find any specific articles online referencing this.